# Spyder-Python crashes when importing graphlab

Tags: python, crash, windows-10, spyder, graphlab

this is my first question here. I've read the article on how to make a good question and  I hope to stay within those guidelines.

Whenever I run `import graphlab`, Spyder2 freezes and then crashes. I tried installing the package many times and all of them show no error message. Actually, sometimes I don't even have to run the script, just by typing `import graphlab` it crashes.

So, what I'm saying is that I get no error message on the console, Spyder just crashes. I'm using Windows 10.

I'm doing a Machine Learning course from Washington University at Coursera. I would rather use scikit learn instead of graphlab but they don't have methods for product recommendation.

Any suggestions on what I could do to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the folder in CMD, Do : spyder --reset

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much @ShekharSamanta!